# Paypal payments standard. Displaying info

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to display information in the comment1 and comment2 fields of the paypal admin interface using paypal payments standard ?

Could not find which variable to use ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you must be referring to the PayPal Manager (manager.paypal.com).  The PayFlow Gateway API is where those comment parameters come into play, and Payments Standard does not utilize this API, so unfortunately that won't work.

Payments Standard does provide a single field called "custom" that you can use to pass your own data.

You may also want to look into [Express Checkout with the PayFlow gateway](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pfp_expresscheckout_pp.pdf) and then you can probably include the comment fields, but I haven't specifically reviewed that documentation or tested it, so I can't say 100% for sure if that would work.

Comment: Thanks, the variables does not seem to exist in PatFlow Gateway too.